# I am not sure why object of A is also getting printed at the last

Tags: java, collections

Could someone please explain me why am I getting this output

```
package code;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class A {
}
class B extends A {
}    
class C extends B {
}
public class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<A> x = new ArrayList<A>();
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        x.add(new A());
        a = x;
        a.add(new B());
        ArrayList b = a;
        ArrayList<C> c = (ArrayList<C>) b;
        c.add(new C());
        a.add(new A()); // I am not sure why object of A is also getting printed at the last
        for (Object obj : c) {
            System.out.println(obj + " class Name " + obj.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
----------
code.A@7852e922 class Name code.A
----------
code.B@4e25154f class Name code.B
----------
code.C@70dea4e class Name code.C
----------
code.A@5c647e05 class Name code.A
----------
```

Comment: I'm getting confused with the output lastLine

Comment: You are only *creating* two `ArrayList` instances and the second one from `ArrayList a = new ArrayList();` is never used, because it is discarded two lines down with value of `a` is replaced. After that, `x`, `a`, `b`, and `c` are all referecing the *same* `ArrayList` object.

Comment: If that's not the output you expect, what *do you* expect, and why?

Comment: You need to clarify your question, because *"explain me why am I getting this output"* does not explain exactly what part of the output you're confused about. The duplicate link explains why your output prints "classname@hexcode".

Comment: @AndyTurner It seems OPs *main* question is the comment in the code, i.e. *"why object of A is also getting printed at the last"*. Question needs to be cleaned up to clarify that that is the question. Both Mureinik (see his [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44604315/revisions) and I (see [dup link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140402/5221149)) thought question was about the `@hashcode` in the output.

Comment: @Andreas You got it please clarify

Comment: @VedPrakash It's *your* question. You clarify it.

Comment: @Andreas I meant,if you know the answer,please do let me know.

Comment: @VedPrakash I [already did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604283/could-someone-please-explain-me-why-am-i-getting-this-output-in-below-program?noredirect=1#comment76195788_44604283), and Mureinik changed [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604315/5221149) to explain too.

Comment: @VedPrakash, The answer is Your arrayList contains the object of class `A` as the last element and hence it is printed. You making `a =x` leaves you with **One and only one** object of ArrayList. You add all the elements in it and then while printing you get what you added. I have mentioned the same in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you use `b=a` you are just saving a reference to a in b. Whatever change you apply to a will also affect b. And since you did `c=b` then c will get affected too. You are not saving a copy of the list then changing the value of one of them, instead you are saving a reference to a in b and c.

So when you used `a.add()` at the end, it was added to b and c too

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `c` are the same object. Let's take a look at the relevant lines of the code:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList(); // a is created
ArrayList b = a; // b holds a reference to the same object
ArrayList<C> c = (ArrayList<C>) b; // and so does c
```

So whenever you add an object to `c`, it will be present in `a` too (since, as noted, they are the same object!).

Comment: I'm confused with the commented portion in my above program

Comment: @VedPrakash oh, I misunderstood the question. See my edited answer.

Comment: Because `c` and `a` reference the same object.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have 4 references of ArrayList : x,a,b and c.

You initially have 2 objects of ArrayList with `a` being the reference to one and `x` being the reference to the other one. But `a = x` makes the object of ArrayList initially referenced by `a` eligible for garbage collection. Now both `a` and `x` refers to same one ArrayList and you already added an object of `A`. Hence ArrayList has `[A]`

Next you add an object of `B` to it so status of arrayList is `[A,B]`. Both `a` and `x` are referring to this list.
Next you create another reference `b` and make it also refer to the object referred by `a` so now you have `a`,`b`,`x` referring to the same list.

Next you create another reference `c` and make it refer to same object as refferred by `b` so now you have 4 references referring to same list. Status of list is `[A,B]`.

Now you add object of `C` in the list using reference `c` followed by adding an object of `A` using reference `a`. Since all the 4 references refer to same one ArrayList hence objects of `A` and `B` both gets added in the list and status of list : `[A,B,C,A]`.

Now when you iterate the list and in `System.out.println()` use the reference to print , the `toString()` method gets invoked and as you have not overriden it hence the method as derieved from `Object.java`  gets invoked.

The answer to your question , as why object of `A` gets printed in the last ? :  Because the list contains it in the last, as explained above. Hope it helps.

Comment: `a = x` does **not** make object of ArrayList initially referenced by `x` eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: oops sorry , i meant arraylist referenced by `a`, thanks for correcting

Comment: I corrected, may I have the -1 reverted please now :)

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning the first `ArrayList`object to all the `ArrayList` references.

```
ArrayList<A> x = new ArrayList<A>();
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
//x.add(new A());
a = x;    //now a & x refer to same object.
//a.add(new B());
ArrayList b = a;    //b refer to the same object.
ArrayList<C> c = (ArrayList<C>) b;   //now a,b,x & c every reference refer the same object.
```

Thus you are assigning elements to the same `ArrayList` throughout the code.

Hope this would be helpful......